# Segmentation fault with ncurses but no problem when -fsanitize is used for building

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb

***Update***

I am getting this segmentation fault with `ncurses` function calls.

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
                                                                                                        
 0x00007ffff3a77f28 in wnoutrefresh () from /lib64/libncurses.so.6

(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff3a77f28 in wnoutrefresh () from /lib64/libncurses.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff3a77feb in wrefresh () from /lib64/libncurses.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff3a7168a in _nc_wgetch () from /lib64/libncurses.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff3a7241b in wgetch () from /lib64/libncurses.so.6
#4  0x0000000000450e85 in process_user_security () at caomenu.pc:12948
#5  0x00000000004501e5 in display_user_security () at caomenu.pc:12780
#6  0x0000000000403932 in menu1 () at caomenu.pc:993
#7  0x00000000004018ca in main (ac=2, av=0x7fffffffe208) at caomenu.pc:562
(gdb)
```

The below is the `process_user_security()` function that accepts input for the required menu option from user. and the statement

`selection=wgetch(User_security_window); /*line number 12948*/`

where it indicated crashing by observing the backtrack of stack trace from gdb.

I am suspecting this as environmental issue. there is some undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include </usr/include/sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <curses.h>

    WINDOW *User_security_window;
  

   /*************************************************************************** */
    /** Function : process_user_security()                                  **/
    /** Purpose  : The purpose of this function is display                   **/
    /**                              Commodities on the screen.             **/
    /* ************************************************************************** */
    void process_user_security(void) {
    int selection = 0;
    int i,z;
    int digitflag =FALSE;
    int number_in_group=0;
    int scrline_holder;
    int exitflag=FALSE;

     /* TDT,II - 02 May 2006 - Added Level 1 Debugging */

   

     if ( iDebug >= 1 )
            WriteTrace( "Running process_user_security" );

    digitcounter = 0;
    field_counter=0;
    for ( ; ; ) {
          selection=wgetch(User_security_window); ===> giving segmentation fault.(line number 12948)

        selection=toupper(selection);

        if ( selection== F8_KEY||selection==KEY_F(8) ) {
            EXEC SQL
            DELETE  CAO.SCRTY_USR_ASGN
            WHERE    USER_ID = :orUserSecurityInfo[usersecurityline].old_user_id;

            EXEC SQL
            COMMIT;

            load_user_data();

            disply_down_user_security(0);
            column_holder = 0;
            user_column = 1;
            memset(new_group_value,  0, sizeof(new_group_value));
            selection = 0;
            usersecurityline=scrline=0;
        };

        if ( (selection== F6_KEY||selection==KEY_F(6))&&(user_column == 50) ) {
            scrline_holder = scrline;

            display_group_id();
            clearok( User_security_window, TRUE );
            mvwaddstr(User_security_window,scrline_holder+9,50,"          ");
```

//function continues like this.

and the below is the `display_user_security()` that initializes and set the window for menu. from this function `process_user_security()` function is called.

```
/****************************************************************************/
/** Function : display_user_security()                       **/
/** Purpose  : The purpose of this function is display pull list.        **/
/****************************************************************************/
void display_user_security(void) {

    int iCount,i,j=0,k;
    int key_pressed,avl_elm,good_key;
    varchar cUser_id[30];
    varchar cUser_name[30];
    varchar cUpdate_user_id[30];
    varchar cUser_password[30];
    varchar cGroup_id[30];

    int selection=0;
    int selection2=0;
    int item_counter;
    int digitflag =FALSE;
    int z,m,n;
    char    A[30],B[30];

/* TDT,II - 02 May 2006 - Added Level 1 Debugging */
    if ( iDebug >= 1 )
        WriteTrace( "Running display_user_security" );

    noecho();

    User_security_window = newwin(0,0,0,0);
    keypad( User_security_window, TRUE );
    clearok( User_security_window, TRUE );

    sprintf(menustr,"CAO USER SECURITY ACCESS");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,1,28,menustr);

    sprintf(menustr,"F6-Select Group Id");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,3,5,menustr);

    sprintf(menustr,"F7-Add User");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,3,30,menustr);

    sprintf(menustr,"F8-Delete User");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,3,60,menustr);

    wmove(User_security_window,9,1);
    wrefresh(User_security_window);

    sprintf(menustr,"F2-First");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,23,5,menustr);
    sprintf(menustr,"F3-Last");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,23,16,menustr);

    sprintf(menustr,"F4-Prev");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,23,26,menustr);
    sprintf(menustr,"F5-Next");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,23,36,menustr);
    sprintf(menustr,"ESC-Back");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,23,46,menustr);

    sprintf(menustr," User     Adminstrator   User       User        Group");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,7,2,menustr);
    sprintf(menustr," Id       Id             Name       Password    Id");
    mvwaddstr(User_security_window,8,2,menustr); 

    clearok( User_security_window, TRUE );
    wrefresh(User_security_window);

    load_user_data();

    disply_down_user_security(0);
    column_holder = 0;
    user_column = 1;
    memset(new_group_value,  0, sizeof(new_group_value));
    selection = 0;
    usersecurityline=scrline=0;
    process_user_security(); // function call to process_user_security()
    delwin(User_security_window);
}
```

and below is the command i use to build the menu  `scrmenu` program.

```
gcc -g -o scrmenu caomenu.c superbox.c -L/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/lib -L/usr/include/ -lclntsh -lncurses -lcurses
```

any suggestion regarding fix for this are welcome.

Comment: You have another bug.  Some more code might help.

Comment: There is most likely a bug somewhere in your code, like writing into freed memory, overwriting a buffer, or something similar which results in undefined behaviour. That's about all we can say without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Any half-decent compiler should warn you against using non-initialized variables. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`. Less head-banging against the wall, more solving the bugs that the compiler has already found and pointed out to you :)

Comment: `-fsanitize=address` can't catch all the bugs. `valgrind` can catch more of them.  (It is _mathematically impossible_ for an automated tool to catch _all_ the bugs: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem>.)

Comment: Note: *'Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence!'*

Comment: @MaheshBabuTatineni don't post clarifications as an answer, instead [edit] your question and put all clarifications into the question.

Comment: Why are you linking to `curses` *and* `ncurses`?  What happens if you link just one?  Generally, there should only be one on the system.

Comment: Also `newwin` can fail.  Check that it didn't return a NULL pointer on you.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited knowledge here, I'm *guessing* this is likely the source of the issue.

```
TrcFile = fopen( cTraceFile, cTrcOpenFlag );
```

There is nothing inherently wrong with this line (except I have no idea what the value of `cTrcOpenFlag` is), but `fopen` can fail!  You must check return value here since `fopen` can return NULL on failure.  The fact that it crashed on the `fclose` may be irrelevant because once you are passing around a NULL pointer all bets are off.  Try this:

```
TrcFile = fopen( cTraceFile, cTrcOpenFlag );
if (TrcFile == NULL) {
    perror(cTraceFile);
    abort();  // replace this with correct error handling...
}
```

This will print out an appropriate error message to the console/terminal.

Another problem I see is the indexing appears to run passed the end of the array here:

```
    memcpy(B,string,size);
    for ( m=0;m<=size;m++ ) {
        if ( B[m]!='\0' )
            A[m]=B[m];
        else {
            for ( n=m;n<=size;n++ ) {
                A[n]=' ';
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    memcpy(string,A,size);
```

According to the `memcpy` calls, `size` is assumed to be correct.  Both for loops appear to run passed `size`. The following loops iterate from 0 to `size` inclusively:

```
for ( m=0;m<=size;m++ ) {
for ( n=m;n<=size;n++ ) {
```

The last iteration is going to access `A[size]` and `B[size]` which is beyond the bounds imposed by `size`.  Whether or not this causes a crash depends on parts of the program I cannot see.

So, I fix these `for` loops to:

```
for ( m=0;m<size;m++ ) {
for ( n=m;n<size;n++ ) {
```

At this point, if `size` is ever 30 or greater, you are going to overrun your array.  This is undefined behavior and will put you in nasal demons territory.  Add this to the top of the function to catch this issue.

```
if (size >= 30) {
   fprintf(stderr, "size >= 30\n");
   abort();
}
```

Keep in mind, these `abort`s are just stubs for debugging.  If it hits an `abort` it will appear like an `exit(1)` that can be caught by your debugger.  You wouldn't leave them in there once you fix your bugs.

Comment: Hi @Jason I have tried this but not worked. It seems no issues with fopen here

Comment: Still segfault at same location?  Asking because `abort` is kind of like a crash that can be caught by a debugger.

Comment: @MaheshBabuTatineni Hey see the edit.  I see another problem.

Comment: hi @Jason Nothing worked. But I am not giving up!  One key is that when i use -`fsanitize=address` while building it, it's not throwing  this fclose() segmentation fault. everything went fine. But  When i build without `-fsanitize`  it's throwing fclose() segfault as shown in above.

Comment: @MaheshBabuTatineni The reason it behaves differently with `-fsanitize=address` is because the executable *is* different.  You have undefined behavior somewhere in your program.  It may not be in the code you've posted either.  Could you edit the question with the code you have now?  You have to start eliminating things until it stops crashing.  I would start with the `WriteTrace` call.  I would not be surprised at all if it still crashes.  Also, try the `-fstack-clash-protection` option.  That will help discover buffer overruns on the stack (something valgrind will not catch).

Comment: Hi @Jason tried eliminating the segmentation fault givers step by step. and it all rooted back to various -lncurses functions most of the time especially at the end. It seems this is environmental issue than of the logic. Digging more and investigating. I will let you know. Thanks for the valuable suggestion. It's a hectic task but worthy. meanwhile `-fstack-clash-protection` didn't find anything.

Comment: Hi @Jason I have edited the question. Added the code where it's indicating crash